# Online remix lost changes made to local smart contract file

Tags: remix, ide

After my online remix crashed a few month ago and lost all the smart contract files, I managed to restore from a backup zip and save all smart contract files to local drive. What I do is to open a smart contract on local drive from remix in default_workspace and edit, assuming that all the change made to the smart contract will be automatically (there is no save button in remix) saved by remix to the local drive. Today I couldn't open a smart contract I am working with from online remix and have to delete it from remix and open it again from the local drive. However the modified date of the local smart contract was long ago and it is not the most current one. The local copy saved some changes but most recent changes were not saved. This is 2nd time I lost files/changes with remix. I guess I must be missing something big with the Remix or Remix is not the right IDE for my application. If I want to edit smart contract files stored locally and any changes go to the local copy, what is the right way to use Remix? Or else what is the good IDE for the application. Shall I install remix locally? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As good as Remix is to start developing as fast as possible, I would consider using a local IDE installation for editing, like Visual Studio Code, or even IntelliJ IDEA or some other JetBrains IDE. All of them have plugins and extensions that enable support for Solidity.

Remix itself gives you a warning when using its daemon for modifying your local files because it is still in its alpha version, and thus it may be buggy from time to time.

If you opt for using Visual Studio Code, you can use [JuanBlanco's Solidity extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity) to enable support for Solidity, and you can use something like [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) or [Truffle Suite](https://trufflesuite.com/) as something to help you setup a local development environment.

Comment: I just installed the REMIX desktop and open a smart contract from local drive. But I am not sure if the REMIX will AUTOMATICALLY save my work.  Is there way I can manually save the sol file to local drive? I didn't fine one and have a concern if change will be saved by REMIX automatically.

Comment: I can't find that anywhere, but I suppose the changes should be saved between each compilation at least, so the compiler can read the latest source code rather than an old version. You can try creating a small `.sol` file, editing it and compiling it, and once you open it in your local machine you should see the changes until you compiled it.